# Python - select string based on length from second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with website as one of the columns. Trying to create a clean string column that excludes everything after .com/ .net / .org / .edu , etc., my approach is to find the location of them and exclude anything after .com/.net by adding appropriate characters

```
**string**  
https:/amazon.com  
google.com/
http:/onlinelearning.edu/home  
walmart.net/  
https:/target.onlinesales.org/home/goods  
https:/target.onlinesales.de/home/goods  

**new string**  
https:/amazon.com    
google.com  
http:/onlinelearning.edu   
walmart.net  
https:/target.onlinesales.org  
https:/target.onlinesales.de
```

for the ones that contains .com

```
df['length'] = np.where(df['string'].str.contains('.com'), df['string'].str.find('.com') + 4, df['string'].str.len())
df['new_string'] = [y[:x] for (x, y) in zip(df['length'], account_dt['string'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for regex. You can use `pd.Series.str.replace` with negative lookbehind:

```
print (df["col"].str.replace("(?<!:)/.*", ""))
```

Or alternatively list out all your req domain by positive lookbehind:

```
print (df["col"].str.replace("(?:(?<=com)|(?<=edu)|(?<=org)|(?<=de)|(?<=net))/.*", ""))

0                -https:/amazon.com
1                       -google.com
2         -http:/onlinelearning.edu
3                      -walmart.net
4    -https:/target.onlinesales.org
5     -https:/target.onlinesales.de
Name: col, dtype: object
```

You can further refine the pattern to suit more cases.